# Telerik ComboBox with picture

Tags: combobox, telerik, kendo-ui, themes

I need a picture in combobox but I have only path

```
var files = Url.Content("~/Content/skin/Simple.png");

@(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
      .Name("ComboBox")
      .BindTo(files.Select(f => new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = f.ToString(), Value = "" }))
   )
```

thank you but if I need to show all pictures in folder

```
string searchFolder = Url.Content("~/Content/skin/");
var filters = new[] { "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "tiff", "bmp" };
var files = Some Class.GetFilesFrom(searchFolder, filters, false);
```

there are my full code

controller

```
public ActionResult Combo()
    {
      return View();
    }
```

model

```
public class Combo
  {
    public static string[] GetFilesFrom(string searchFolder, string[] filters, bool isRecursive)
    {
      var filesFound = new List<String>();
      var searchOption = isRecursive ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
      foreach (var filter in filters)
      {
        filesFound.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(searchFolder, String.Format("*.{0}", filter), searchOption));
      }
      return filesFound.ToArray();
    }
  }
```

and View

```
@using TETRA.RS.WWW.UI.Models

@{
  string searchFolder = Url.Content("~/Content/skin/");
  var filters = new[] { "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "tiff", "bmp" };
  var files = Combo.GetFilesFrom(searchFolder, filters, false);
}


@(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
      .Name("ComboBox")
      .BindTo(files.Select(f => new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = f, Value = "" }))
)
```

And I see only full path in combobox
And I do not Know how many pictures in a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of adding images to an item selectable from a radcombobox, each has their benefits and the most suitable can only be defined by your requirements.

The easiest way is to assign a value to the ImageUrl attribute.
(Telerik Documentation: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-appearance-item-images.html)

Alternatively you could modify the item template. (Telerik Demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: Do you have the current code? Are you wanting to put multiple images per item (i.e. is each item a separate folder)? Have you looked at the File Manager control? (Telerik Demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/filemanagers/defaultcs.aspx#qsf-demo-source)

Answer (score 0):

I have used Kendo UI 
I have a folder with pictures and I don't Know how much there are
I need to get all the pictures and use in comboBox

Method finds all pictures

```
public static string[] GetFilesFrom(string searchFolder, string[] filters, bool isRecursive)
  {
    var filesFound = new List<string>();
    var searchOption = isRecursive ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
    foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
      filesFound.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(searchFolder, String.Format("*.{0}", filter), searchOption));
    }
    return filesFound.Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();
  }
```

SettingsController

```
public ActionResult Theme()
    {
      return View();
    }

    public JsonResult ThemeJson()
    {
      string searchFolder = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Content\\themes\\skin");
      var filters = new[] { "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "tiff", "bmp" };
      var files = Tools.GetFilesFrom(searchFolder, filters, false);
      return Json(files.Select(f => new { Id = f, Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f) }));
    }
```

and View

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
          .Name("customers")
          .DataTextField("Name")
          .DataValueField("Id")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { })
          .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("ThemeJson", "Settings").Type(HttpVerbs.Post)))
          .Filter("startswith")
          .Height(300)
          .Template("<img src=\"" + Url.Content("~/Content/themes/skin/") + "${data.Id}\" alt=\"${data.Id}\" />" +
                        "<dl>" +
                        "Name theme: ${ data.Name }" +
                        "</dl>")
)
```

also you need add reference kendo.all.min.js and Kendo.Mvc.UI